# Android - Reading memory of another process programmatically

Tags: android, ios, memory, root, dump

Game mod apps like `XmodGames` are certainly able to read another process's memory, because it needs to get some variables which belong to the game's process.

It is known that on `Android` it needs root and on `iOS` jailbreak.

So how does it manage to do this programmatically, because as far as I know, `Android` has no `API` for reading another `process's memory`, `iOS` also.

It looks like the mod uses some `low-level kernel syscalls` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look on IPC and AIDL?